# VBA arrays and Operators

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel, vba, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write a couple lines of code in VBA for excel, here is what the VB.Net version of the code looks like.

```
            ThisVariable <<= 8

        Variable.Add(ThisVariable)
```

How do I write these lines of code in VBA?  VBA does not have  the "<<=" operator and does not have the .Add property of an array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, VBA doesn't have built in bit shifting, but you can add a function that does it for you. [Try this one.](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/bit-shifting-function.shtml)

For the second question, to increase an array size, you have to use the ReDim command. [Here's the info on that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8k3cys2.aspx)

Also, you could use a collection instead of an array. With a collection, you can add & delete item within it at will.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

`<<=` left-shifts the number by 8 binary digits, i.e. multiplies the number by 256. For adding something to an array you can re-dim the array:

```
ThisVariable = ThisVariable * 256
Dim U As Long
Dim L As Long
L = LBound (Variable)
U = UBound (Variable)
ReDim Preserve Variable (L To U+1)
Variable (U+1) = ThisVariable
```

Note that redim'ing the array just to add an element is not very efficient. You should try to find another approach (e.g. use a larger array and store the number of "valid" elements in a counter variable -- or even create a class module for that).